# Using selected columns in a WHERE EXISTS query in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I have a table which is related to itself, with columns vin, type and sn. I want to find all rows with type of 2 that have only one row with type of 1; I tried this:

```
 select count(*) as aggregate 
 from `data` as `t1` 
 where `type` = 2 
   and `last_service` < DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH) 
   and exists (
                select count(*) as data.count 
                from `data` 
                where count=1 
                  and `type` = 1
               )
```

but I keep getting the following error:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '`.count from`data`where count=1 and`type`= ?)' at line 1`.

Comment: Please note that the community has recently discussed [adding "urgent" begging to questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495), and the firm consensus is that it is not acceptable. Please don't add this to your posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is syntax error because you use alias as complex identifier: `as data.count`. Try `as data_count` instead.

Comment: tried this but it still says unknown column data_count

Comment: Try this one as exists() subquery: `select count(*) as   data_count from data  where type = 1 having data_count=1`

Comment: You can't use selected fields' aliases in the query's `WHERE` clause, it needs to be in a `HAVING` one.

Comment: That's true @Uueerdo

Answer (score 0):

you cannot assign data to table column like that. 
Try

```
select count(*) as count from data where count=1 and type = 1


select count(*) as count from data having count(*) = 1 and type = 1
```

Comment: You cannot use dynamically generated in where clause